# Shortest time between separated yellow card cautions for one player?

Tags: football, officiating

In the June 10th Copa America match between USA and Paraguay, USA defender DeAndre Yedlin was cautioned with a yellow card, and then [57 seconds later](http://www.usnews.com/news/sports/articles/2016-06-11/us-reaches-copa-america-quarters-with-1-0-win-over-paraguay) was cautioned a second time and sent off for accumulation of two yellows.  Is this the shortest time between two cautions for one player?  Limit answers to senior international and professional teams.

This is different that the question found here: [Can a player receive two yellow cards if advantage is played?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12551/can-a-player-receive-two-yellow-cards-if-advantage-is-played).  Both cards could be awarded at the same stoppage of play, but I am looking for a case of "A player knows he has been cautioned, but immediately proceeds to commit another offense" instead of "player commits two offenses when he technically doesn't know he was going to be cautioned for the first offense".

Comment: Di Maria cautioned for failure to respect the required distance twice in a number of seconds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqwZusZCG04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious scenario for this is a player being booked for any reason, then showing obvious dissent to the referee, and receiving a second yellow card before play is restarted.

An example of this happened to Brad Evans, captain of the Seattle Sounders, in a [match against Colorado Rapids](http://www.skysports.com/football/colorado-vs-seattle/353458) in April 2016.

The match report shows two yellows in the 86th Minute:

- 86'  Brad Evans (Seattle Sounders FC) is shown the yellow card.
- 86' Second yellow card to Brad Evans (Seattle Sounders FC).

According to the [News Tribune reporter Don Luiz](https://twitter.com/donruiztnt/status/724085143489540097), Evans explained the cards like this:

> I asked [the ref] how [the tackle] was different to my tackle in the first half. He said "It's different, it's different'. I said you need to talk to me. He said no. I gave him an expletive; he gave me a yellow card. I said it's your duty to talk to me on the field. He said "No it's not'. I gave him another expletive, and that was the double yellow.

I doubt that this is the record, as Evans and the referee had a short discussion between the two cards, and assume that there must have been quicker double yellows in similar circumstances.